# Adding an object to a react hook array causes it to turn null

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have an empty array of objects set up

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);
```

I can add the first element easy...

```
setFilters(prevState => [...prevState, {name: e.target.name, value: e.target.value}])
```

I can console log that and get a perfect array with one object.

When I go to add the second filter using the same code above and then console log it I get `NULL`.

Here's the interesting part though. If I console log the whole thing.

```
setFilters(prevState => console.log([...prevState, {name: e.target.name, value: e.target.value}]))
```

I get the array of objects that I need.

Comment: We will need more of the code you got here. I assume you're running all of this in the same function and React can't split a function on re-render when you change the `filters` state on the top of the function and then again below. So share your function and we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're referencing `e.target.name` you might be running into the common issue of React de-referencing your event objects. Basically, React re-uses `e`, and because of the asyncronous order of execution of React hook state updates, `e.target` may be undefined by the time your state update executes.

Try this:

```
const newObject = {name: e.target.name, value: e.target.value};

setFilters(prevState => {
  return [...prevState, newObject];
)
```

It's a subtle difference, but you need to "capture" the values of `e.target` *before* calling `setFilters()`, because your state update function is not executed synchronously right away, it enters the React update queue and is executed later.